# Office 365 API request timeout

Tags: azure, office365

I am developing a 3rd party application to integrate with Office 365 and I have a question about request timeout. Timeout I set is 25 seconds which is more than enough from my perspective, however my requests end up with timeout frequently.

Here is log of what I am doing:

I sent 2 GET requests 1 by one to following url: 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars'

1) 'client-request-id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Error: ETIMEDOUT

2) 'client-request-id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Completed request GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars in 22.393 seconds.

I have double checked region of my azure active directory - it points to right place, so geographical distance should not be a problem.

How can I make sure that request will be processed in shorter amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known delay in the Office 365 APIs that we're working to improve. We have fixes in the pipeline that we believe will help here, so hopefully you'll see an improvement in the near future.